# Customized Android Spinner

Tags: android, spinner

First of all my apologies, I am very new to Android.  I am trying to "wrap a skin" around the Android spinner widget.  I want to totally control the look.  The spinner will always contain simple single-line text items.  Specifically here are the changes I want to make:

1. The header has a specific background, a specific font, and a custom arrow image on the right.
2. The arrow needs to flip over vertically (point up) when the drop down list is open.  Points down when list closed.
3. The background of the drop down list needs to be custom.  Has rounded corners, certain colors etc.
4. Each item in the list has the same look but I want to control the look (font and font color at the very least but controlling the divider line length and color is also needed)
5. The list needs to make a click sound when opened and closed.  This one is tough.  Other widgets seem to do this but spinners dont seem to.

There are very few things you can change in a spinner.  Any pointing in the right direction would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check out [this demo from Android Example](http://androidexample.com/Custom_Spinner_With_Image_And_Text_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=84&aaid=107), which you could customise to suit your exact requirements, or generally pull ideas from.

Comment: The question is quite vague, so I suppose a vague answer with a link isn't too bad in this circumstance, although it would be better if you could provide some other examples.